# SQL select items that span entire range of attribute

Tags: sql, select, jdbc, toggle, derby

The title might sound a little unclear, hopefully my description will be clearer!
Here is what I am trying to do. I have a table with 3 columns, id, value, and a binary attribute. i want to select items from the table that have the same name, but opposing binary attributes, so for example

```
ID|Value     |Toggle
====================
0 |noun      |no
1 |verb      |no
2 |noun      |yes
3 |adjective |yes
4 |article   |no
5 |noun      |no
6 |adjective |yes
7 |verb      |no
8 |article   |yes
```

on this table, the returned records would be

```
ID|Value     |Toggle
====================
0 |noun      |no
2 |noun      |yes
4 |article   |no
5 |noun      |no
8 |article   |yes
```

all noun records and all article records would be returned because there exist noun records that have no and yes, and article records that have no and yes.

adjective would not be returned because both records have a toggle of yes, and verb would not be returned because both records have a toggle of no. Thanks for reading!

PLEASE ask me any follow up questions if my description is still not clear. I am using Derby with JDBC, if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work for you, I would be interested to know how quick/slow this would be (if you have an index on tog, it would be very fast)....I assume the table name is t and the column value is val and the column toggle is tog :)

```
SELECT * FROM T 
WHERE  tog = 'yes' and val in (select val from t where tog='no')

UNION 

SELECT * FROM T 
WHERE  tog = 'no'  and val in (select val from t where tog='yes')
```

Comment: I actually fixed the speed issue due to an oversight I had made initially. There are more columns in my table than I cited in the example, there are actually a group of users, 1 of which each listing is attributed to with a uid foreign key. by only looking at 1 user at a time, which is actually the desired functionality, it works "fast enough," but I might try to experiment with your addition to see if I can get it to go any faster.
Right now I am using this:
`select * from items as a where TOGGLE='yes' and UID=1
and exists(
select * from items as b 
where a.title=b.title and b.TOGGLE='no'
)`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If you have a UID, then it is more correct to write the query in a better way. Either modify the one suggested by @cmd to include the UID or consider moving the question to http://dba.stackexchange.com/?as=1 where you may get a better answer. Due to circumstances, I can't provide a better answer at the moment, but your question is interesting (+1)!.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
select * from table a
where exists (
select 1 from table b
where a.Value = b.Value
and a.ID != b.ID
and a.Toggle != b.Toggle
)
```

Comment: after reading about what exists does, this looks like it would work, but the query is taking forever to execute on 12500 records.

Comment: But my question of course just included my example, for which this code did work. Also, exists is a good step in the right direction for my overall solution. Thanks!

Comment: also a.ID!=b.ID is redundant given a.Toggle!=b.Toggle since ID is a primary key

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct a.* from my_table a
  join my_table b on a.Value = b.Value and a.Toggle != b.Toggle
```